# Do I risk refusal of a future work permit in France?

Tags: visa, working-visas, france, employment

I'm a foreigner who has worked a CDD in France with a travailleur temporaire visa.

In this past job, I was not allowed to seek any side jobs (it would have been a cumul d'activité not authorized under that visa's terms and no way around it…), but I didn't realize this and I responded to an ad for a nannying gig. There was no contract made but I did a couple hours with them, before I did some research and found out I wasn't supposed to. I informed them that I couldn't work for them but they'd already paid me for the couple hours through a CESU check (thus leaving a paper trail…). Nothing happened with my main job and I left France but now I'm concerned about what could happen if anyone were to find out and I were to try to come back. I'm not sure how bad this will look.

If I asked for a new permit in the future and had to go through OFII/DIRECCTE, would they be likely to search through my background and see this one suspicious paycheck/past inscription with CESU and then I wouldn't ever be able to work or study in France ever again? It sounds extreme for just one mistake but as it's already hard to get a permit for France as a foreigner, I'm really worried about what could happen later on. Am I just being paranoid? Does anyone have any insight or advice about this issue?

Comment: Formally, it sounds like it could be held against you but don't overstimate the extent of the data sharing or the thoroughness of investigations when issuing a visa.